# Nginx compiled with couchbase-nginx-module high CPU usage

Tags: nginx, couchbase

I'm testing couchbase_nginx module with ngx_srcache module to store data in couchbase. I use https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-nginx-module to compile and installed the setup according to the guides and no problem faced.

After few browsing the Nginx CPU utilization goes 100% and browser client can't download remaining data and nginx process frozen. Here is my configurations

```
# ./sbin/nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.3.7
built by gcc 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6) (GCC)
configure arguments: --prefix=/opt/nginx-couchbase --with-debug --add-module=../nginx-    couchbase-module-0.3.1 --add-module=./contrib/srcache-nginx-module-master --add-module=./contrib/memc-nginx-module-master

nginx.conf:
....
        location /cb {
        internal;
        set $couchbase_key $arg_key;
        set $couchbase_cmd $arg_cmd;
        set $couchbase_val $arg_val;
        couchbase_connect_timeout 6ms;
        couchbase_timeout 3ms;
    add_header X-Couchbase-Flags $couchbase_flags;
        couchbase_pass localhost:8091,127.0.0.1:8091,localhost bucket=default;
    }

    location / {
        set $key $uri$args;
        srcache_fetch GET /cb key=$key;
        srcache_store PUT /cb key=$key;
        srcache_store_statuses 200 301 302;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.61:8080;
            proxy_set_header  Accept-Encoding  "";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    Host        $http_host;


    }
```

...

```
# rpm -qa | grep couchbase
couchbase-server-2.0.1-170.x86_64
libcouchbase2-core-2.1.2-1.x86_64

# cat cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.1 (Santiago)
```

Please find the nginx error log here - http://pastebin.com/JqgTkZmV

Note that I can set/get using following URLs and stress test with any problem

```
curl -v 'http://localhost:8080/cb?cmd=set&key=foo&val=bar'
curl -v  'http://localhost:8080/cb?cmd=get&key=foo'
```

Appreciate help.